# Django PyTests - Visual Studio code - No tests discovered, please check the configuration settings for the tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

VS Code keeps failing to discover Unit tests for my Django project.

I have installed `pytest` and `pytest-django` libraries

**Project structure** (simplified)

```
- root_project
    - pytest.ini
    - etc
    - docs
    - tests
       - test_app.py
    - django_project
        - project_name
            - settings
                - develop.py
                - testing.py
                - production.py
            - app_1
            - app_2
            - manage.py
```

**pytest.ini** file content

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "django_project.project_name.settings.testing"
python_files = test_*.py
```

**settings.json** file content

```
 "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "root_project/tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": false,
```

I keep getting this error and no tests are discovered:

[image: Error]

Comment: Are the tests found when running from terminal?

Comment: Yes they are. I have to add env var tDJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and I have to run command py.test from directory root_project/django_project/project_name

Comment: Does using the pytest args in vscode settings help?  e.g. `"python.testing.pytestArgs": [ ... ]`